# All images put to storage are saved as 'octet-stream' rather than image/jpeg

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I have been building this camera function in my application and when the image is captured it is supposed to send it as a jpg but it sends as an 'octet-stream' my code is shown below please any help would be great.

```
    const photo = await camera.takePictureAsync()
    console.log(photo)
    setPreviewVisible(true)
    //setStartCamera(false)
    setCapturedImage(photo)
  }
  const __savePhoto = async () => {
    const uploadUri = await fetch(capturedImage.uri);

    try {
      await firebase.storage().ref('Non-Verified Photos/').put(uploadUri);
       Alert.alert(
         'Image uploaded!',
         'Your image has been sent for review!'
       )
     }catch(e){
       console.log(e);
     }

     setCapturedImage(null)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems no content type detection is being done for you. You can set your own content type explicitly, as shown in the documentation on [adding metadata to a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata):

```
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

// Upload the file and metadata
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg').put(file, metadata);
```

Comment: The image is still not showing this just changed the type. The problem I have is the image is stored in an array with width,uri,height. It seems the uri is not being pulled separately Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: your question was about the type when you upload the image, and above is the way to change that. If you're also having a problem when loading the image, I recommend asking a separate question about that.